# Is the beaufort cipher just as secure as the Vigenere cipher?

Tags: vigenere

Does the Beaufort cipher have the same strength as the vigenere cipher assuming you use the same complexity of key, or because of it's reciprocal nature make it less secure?

Comment: What is the Beaufort cipher? Any ref?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.  The [Beaufort cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaufort_cipher) is identical to the Vigenère cipher except that, in effect, the plaintext alphabet is reversed (i.e. mapped `A` → `Z`, `B` → `Y`, etc.) before encryption (and after decryption).  The reversal adds no appreciable security, but it also cannot make the cipher *less* secure.